# VirtualBox pausing VMs at random moments when I am not using them... why?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, virtualbox

I have two VirtualBox VMs running headless and they run all the time. A third VM (Windows 7 x64) runs on my desktop in the VirtualBox GUI and is sometimes not used for hours or days.

Ever since I upgraded to VirtualBox 4 I find that Windows VM paused when I switch to it.

Any ideas why VirtualBox would pause my VM without me telling it to?

Mac OS X 10.6 Xeon.

Comment: Maybe the guest is putting itself to sleep? I don't know VirtualBox, but it may have grown new sleep mode features that the guest is now using.

Comment: That was it! Repeat it as an answer and get the points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keith answered this in the comments:

Maybe the guest is putting itself to sleep? I don't know VirtualBox, but it may have grown new sleep mode features that the guest is now using.